# what is the causes of this error System.ArgumentException

Tags: asp.net

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'jobId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult JobDetail(Int32)

Comment: When you ask the question here then you have to provide some snippets of your code so can others will get idea and give the solution

Comment: Change `jobId` to `Id` which will hit your default route or create a custom route